# Ruby / Rails slice array base on range of values and priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes

```
a = [
    {start_time: 9am, end_time: 10am},
    {start_time: 10am, end_time: 11am},
    {start_time: 11am, end_time: 12am},
    {start_time: 1pm, end_time: 2pm},
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 3pm},
    {start_time: 3pm, end_time: 4pm},
    {start_time: 4pm, end_time: 5pm},
    {start_time: 5pm, end_time: 6pm}
    ]
```

And another array of date ranges and priorities - 1 being highest priority

```
p = [
    {start_time: 11am, end_time: 3pm, priority: 1},
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 5pm, priority: 2},
    {start_time: 9am, end_time: 6m, priority: 3}
    ]
```

So if you apply this to the previous array

```
a = [
    {start_time: 9am, end_time: 10am}, #has priority 3
    {start_time: 10am, end_time: 11am}, #has priority 3
    {start_time: 11am, end_time: 12am}, #has priority 3 & 1
    {start_time: 1pm, end_time: 2pm}, #has priority 3 & 1
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 3pm}, #has priority 3 & 2 & 1
    {start_time: 3pm, end_time: 4pm}, #has priority 3 & 2
    {start_time: 4pm, end_time: 5pm}, #has priority 3 & 2
    {start_time: 5pm, end_time: 6pm} #has priority 3
    ]
```

I would like to slice the array at each range based on priority. So step 1 would slice array at priority 1:

```
a = [
    {start_time: 9am, end_time: 10am}, 
    {start_time: 10am, end_time: 11am}, 
    [{start_time: 11am, end_time: 12am}, #priority 1
    {start_time: 1pm, end_time: 2pm}, #priority 1
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 3pm}], #priority 1
    {start_time: 3pm, end_time: 4pm}, 
    {start_time: 4pm, end_time: 5pm}, 
    {start_time: 5pm, end_time: 6pm} 
    ]
```

Priority 2 can't be sliced at it start point because it is owned by priority 1. So takes the earliest available starting point:

```
a = [
    {start_time: 9am, end_time: 10am}, 
    {start_time: 10am, end_time: 11am}, 
    [{start_time: 11am, end_time: 12am}, #priority 1
    {start_time: 1pm, end_time: 2pm}, #priority 1
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 3pm}], #priority 1
    [{start_time: 3pm, end_time: 4pm}, #priority 2
    {start_time: 4pm, end_time: 5pm}], #priority 2
    {start_time: 5pm, end_time: 6pm} 
    ]
```

The remainder becomes priority 3 and I would like to split the arrays if the `start_time` doesn't match the previous `end_time`. So the final result I'm after is:

```
a = [
    [{start_time: 9am, end_time: 10am},  #priority 3
    {start_time: 10am, end_time: 11am}], #priority 3
    [{start_time: 11am, end_time: 12am}], #priority 1 - note times aren't consecutive here
    [{start_time: 1pm, end_time: 2pm}, #priority 1
    {start_time: 2pm, end_time: 3pm}], #priority 1
    [{start_time: 3pm, end_time: 4pm}, #priority 2
    {start_time: 4pm, end_time: 5pm}], #priority 2
    [{start_time: 5pm, end_time: 6pm}] #priority 3
    ]
```

---

I've attempted to build an algorithm for this. It basically goes through each priority by order, selects from the range and moves it over to a new array.

```
p_blocks = []
    p.sort_by! { |x| x.[:priority] }
    p.each do |block|
        f = getReach(a, block[:start_time], block[:end_time])
        f = x.slice_when { |x, y| x[:end_time] != y[:start_time]}.to_a if f.length > 0
        p_blocks << f.flatten
        a-f # remove from array
    end

    return p_blocks

def getReach(logs, start_time, end_time)
    reach = logs.select { |time_log| # get all logs within range  
        ((time_log[:start_time] < end_time and time_log[:start_time] > start_time) or
        (time_log[:end_time] > start_time and time_log[:end_time] < end_time))
        }.sort_by! { |x| x[:start_time] }
    return reach
end
```

However it doesn't work and I'm probably flattening things when I don't need to and it can be slow with large data sets.

If you could offer any help that would be awesome.

Comment: Ryan, you need to step back and state in words what your ultimate objective is and the approach you have chosen to take. Right now you've just laid out a series of steps without telling the reader where you are going and why. It's sort of like me telling someone to get in their car, drive four blocks, turn left, drive six block, turn right..., without informing them of their destination or my reasons for selecting that particular route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [{:start_time=>9, :end_time=>10}, {:start_time=>10, :end_time=>11}, {:start_time=>11, :end_time=>12}, {:start_time=>13, :end_time=>14}, {:start_time=>14, :end_time=>15}, {:start_time=>15, :end_time=>16}, {:start_time=>16, :end_time=>17}, {:start_time=>17, :end_time=>18}] 

p = [{start_time: 11, end_time: 3+12, priority: 1},
    {start_time: 2+12, end_time: 5+12, priority: 2},
    {start_time: 9, end_time: 6+12, priority: 3}
    ]

p.each {|i| a.each {|j| j[:priority] = i[:priority] if (j[:priority].nil?) && (i[:start_time]..i[:end_time]).include?(j[:start_time]) && (i[:start_time]..i[:end_time]).include?(j[:end_time])}}

a
```

Output:

```
# => [{:start_time=>9, :end_time=>10, :priority=>3}, {:start_time=>10, :end_time=>11, :priority=>3}, {:start_time=>11, :end_time=>12, :priority=>1}, {:start_time=>13, :end_time=>14, :priority=>1}, {:start_time=>14, :end_time=>15, :priority=>1}, {:start_time=>15, :end_time=>16, :priority=>2}, {:start_time=>16, :end_time=>17, :priority=>2}, {:start_time=>17, :end_time=>18, :priority=>3}]
```

Hope you can deal with converting am/pm to 24-hour format.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer. I will suggest how you might go about adding the priorities to `a` and then slice for priority `1`. Beyond that, I don't understand what you are doing and what your ultimate objective is. If the question is clarified, I could perhaps elaborate some.

Although I will only answer part of your question, I thought I had something useful to say data structures, code organization and techniques for performing some of the calculations you need to do.

**Reorganize data and create helper methods**

Firstly, let's put `a` in the more convenient form. Note that you need the times in quotes:

```
a = [
    {start_time:  "9am", end_time: "10am"},
    {start_time: "10am", end_time: "11am"},
    {start_time: "11am", end_time: "12am"},
    {start_time:  "1pm", end_time:  "2pm"},
    {start_time:  "2pm", end_time:  "3pm"},
    {start_time:  "3pm", end_time:  "4pm"},
    {start_time:  "4pm", end_time:  "5pm"},
    {start_time:  "5pm", end_time:  "6pm"}
    ]
```

Two helper methods for doing that:

```
def convert(str)
  str.to_i + ((str[-2]=='p') ? 12 : 0)
end

def change(h)
  { interval: convert(h[:start_time])..convert(h[:end_time]) }
end
```

Now let's convert `a` to a structure that's easier to work with (without mutating `a`):

```
b = a.each_with_object([]) { |h,a| a << change(h) }
  #=> [{:interval=> 9..10}, {:interval=>10..11}, {:interval=>11..12},
  #    {:interval=>13..14}, {:interval=>14..15}, {:interval=>15..16},
  #    {:interval=>16..17}, {:interval=>17..18}]
```

Let's do the same for `p`:

```
p = [
    {start_time: "11am", end_time: "3pm", priority: 1},
    {start_time:  "2pm", end_time: "5pm", priority: 2},
    {start_time:  "9am", end_time: "6pm", priority: 3}
    ]

q = p.each_with_object([]) do |h,a|
  a << change(h).merge(priority: h[:priority])
end
  #=> [{:interval=>11..15, :priority=>1},
  #    {:interval=>14..17, :priority=>2},
  #    {:interval=> 9..18, :priority=>3}]
```

Let's also define a helper to determine if two ranges overlap:

```
def overlap?(r1,r2)
  !(r1.first >= r2.last || r1.last <= r2.first)
end
```

Check it:

```
overlap?( 1..10, 10..20) #=> false
overlap?( 1..11, 10..20) #=> true 
overlap?(12..16, 10..20) #=> true 
overlap?( 1..30, 10..20) #=> true 
overlap?(20..30, 10..20) #=> false
```

**Add priorities**

We can now quite easily add priorities for each hash in `b`:

```
b.each do |h|
  h[:priority] = []
  q.each do |g|
    h[:priority] << g[:priority] if overlap?(h[:interval], g[:interval])
  end      
end     
b #=> [{:interval=> 9..10, :priority=>[3]},
  #    {:interval=>10..11, :priority=>[3]},
  #    {:interval=>11..12, :priority=>[1, 3]},
  #    {:interval=>13..14, :priority=>[1, 3]},
  #    {:interval=>14..15, :priority=>[1, 2, 3]},
  #    {:interval=>15..16, :priority=>[2, 3]},
  #    {:interval=>16..17, :priority=>[2, 3]},
  #    {:interval=>17..18, :priority=>[3]}]
```

**Slicing for priority 1**

In this particular case, the hashes having priority `1` are contiguous, so we can replace them with an array, as you requested. I do not know, however, if they will necessarily be contiguous with other data.

```
c = b.each_with_object([]) do |h,a|
  if h[:priority].include?(1)
    if a.empty? || a.last.is_a?(Hash)
      a << [h]
    else
      a.last << h
    end
  else
    a << h
  end
end
  #=> [ {  :interval=>9..10,  :priority=>[3]},
  #     {  :interval=>10..11, :priority=>[3]},
  #     [ {:interval=>11..12, :priority=>[1, 3]},
  #       {:interval=>13..14, :priority=>[1, 3]},
  #       {:interval=>14..15, :priority=>[1, 2, 3]}],
  #     {  :interval=>15..16, :priority=>[2, 3]},
  #     {  :interval=>16..17, :priority=>[2, 3]},
  #     {  :interval=>17..18, :priority=>[3]}]
```